# HikariConfig and maxPoolSize

Tags: spring, postgresql, datasource, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I use HikariConfig as DataSource of postgres database on spring server.
Should I set up maxPoolSize? (default value is -1)
How much pool size can i use?
Are there any dependencies with hardware?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `maxPoolSize` is an indicator as a limit for your application. You should calculate that based on the traffic/ app's overhead / hardware. F.E you could set the limit to 10000 connections , which doesnt mean that it will operate as expected. Actually this will get affected by your hardware , because if your machine contains one core , the 100000 active connections will just stretch both the java application and the postgres as the OS will struggle to handle all those I/O calls. Even worse , if the database and the java app are in different machines in the same network , you also have the network overhead.

What actually optimizes the performance is the `minimumIdle` property along with the `idleTimeout` , so if you have calculated a proper value for those , then it should never reach the `maxConnection` value as well as cause overhead due to lock waiting or resource starvation. The only bad here , is that if your application is wrong designed(f.e. holding the connection longer than needed, not properly committing the transactions, not using batch jobs for long operations) , then it will affect the User's Experience, but this is another question.

i)

> *Should I set up maxPoolSize? (default value is -1)*

You should set it as a global limit so that both your app and database will be maintainable and healthy. The default value is not -1 but 10. More details  [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)

ii)

> *How much pool size can i use?*

That depends on your application and your infrastructure. The only way you could get those numbers is by integrated tests for the most stretching Use Cases.
Some info [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) regarding the postgres tuning

iii)

> *Are there any dependencies with hardware?*

Yes there are , for both the JVM and the Postgres server and also not only from hardware perspective , but also what OS you might choose

Comment: About MinimumIdle:  "[..] However, for maximum performance and responsiveness to spike demands, we recommend not setting this value and instead allowing HikariCP to act as a fixed size connection pool. Default: same as maximumPoolSize" https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby

Answer (score 3):

I arrived here at this question because I, too, wanted to understand what a -1 default for maxPoolSize and minIdle means. Both of these properties default to -1 inside of the internals of HikariConfig. The Hikari code reconciles these values into the defaults that are advertised publicly in the documentation.

```
public HikariConfig()
{
    dataSourceProperties = new Properties();
    healthCheckProperties = new Properties();

    minIdle = -1;
    maxPoolSize = -1;
    maxLifetime = MAX_LIFETIME;
    ...
```

These values are then set as such:

```
    if (maxPoolSize < 1) {
      maxPoolSize = DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE;
    }

    if (minIdle < 0 || minIdle > maxPoolSize) {
      minIdle = maxPoolSize;
    }
```

Not intended to be a direct answer to OP's question, just adding clarity for anyone else who may land here looking for what -1 means.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - struggled with getting the HikariConfig to take notice of values supplied like

```
HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig();    
hc.addDataSourceProperty("maxPoolSize","5");
```

Which appears in some (older I think) code samples.  So make sure you use

```
HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig();
hc.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
...
```